# MariaDB 10.5 sys schema not installable

Tags: mariadb

I user this command:

```
mysql -u root -p < ./sys_10.sql
```

for my MariaDB 10.5.9 published here: https://github.com/FromDual/mariadb-sys

but i got error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 78 in file: './views/p_s/metrics_56.sql': Unknown column 'STATUS' in 'field list'
```

Any solution how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
In the install script look for two references to information_schema.INNODB_METRICS, above that there is an IF statement in the SELECT

simply replace this line

```
IF(STATUS = 'enabled', 'YES', 'NO') AS Enabled
with 
'YES' AS Enabled
```

and another line

```
IF(STATUS = ''enabled'', ''YES'', ''NO'') AS Enabled
with
''YES''AS Enabled
```

I have assumed that since they removed the STATUS column from INNODB_METRICS then they are always enabled.